# What's the alternative to Azure Cloud Service (Classic)?

Tags: wcf, azure, virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

Considering Azure Cloud Services are considered 'classic' and MS is steering towards using the Resource Manager.

What is the recommended path for hosting a WCF webservice? I used to do this with a Azure Cloud Service so I didn't have to manage a Virtual Machine, but I can't find the obvious successor to Cloud Services.

Comment: Did the people flagging this question as opinion-based even read the question?? sigh...

Comment: No, usualy moderators on StackOverflow have their opinion.
And some how their opinion is fine but opinions of other people is not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At this moment, there's no alternative considering the PaaS model. It's possible to use App Service, but the limitations would be a downer.

Cloud Services are far from being deprecated and the support is available on the new portal, so it's safe to assume you won't have any problems using it in the medium term.

Alternatively, you could use Virtual Machine extensions to easy deployment and configuration. See below for details:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-extensions-features/

**Update**:

Azure Service Fabric is now the recommended platform to replace Cloud Services. Overall architecture remains the same and can be migrated without much effort.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-differences

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Support for Classic Cloud Services is available on the portal but there is no way to create non-classic Cloud Services nor is there any published plan to add anything like that.

Comment: Web Roles can be easily replaced by App Service and Worker roles by Web Jobs. I think that's why they are not bringing CS to ARM.